# Tkinter PhotoImage Error: couldn't recognize data in image file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

I am working on winows 7 and **python** 3.8.2. I have an error.
I wanted to upload an Image in a tkinter window. I tried importing a .gif file and I get an error as

"couldn't recognize data in image file". Though the file is in the correct path the error is happening.
Can you please help me?

Here is the Code

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("try")
canvas = Canvas(window, height = 500, width = 500)
canvas.pack()
my_image = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\jeeva\\Pictures\\bulbon.gif")
canvas.create_image(0, 0,  anchor = NW, image = my_image)
window.mainloop()
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\Tanmay_new\python\Codes\Not Finished\tett.py", line 6, in <module>
    my_image = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\jeeva\\Pictures\\bulbon.gif")
  File "C:\Users\jeeva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\jeeva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\jeeva\Pictures\bulbon.gif"
```

Thank you,
Regards,
Tanmay

Comment: Are you sure this is a gif? You didn't just rename a .png file with a .gif suffix, did you?

Comment: Oh. Thank You very much! That was the Problem.

Comment: @Bryan You can add it as an answer so I can upvote it.